# Git pull request showing other developers commits

Tags: git

I am wanting to commit my files - the ones from 15hr ago but why is it showing me other developers commits from august?

[image]

Comment: Did you base your commits directly off the master branch (into which you want to merge)? It looks like you used a different branch to which other people have contributed; a branch that has not been merged with the master. Then, when you request a pull, the entire difference between your branch and the destination branch shows up. Either this is what you want, or you should rebase your commits off the master branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were ahead by `X` number of commits from the remote repository HEAD (or different ref). So you **pulled**, which basically means you obtained commits from other developers in order to be up-to-date.

---

You added some code into your current branch which isn't yours. That is a valid reason why it won't be displayed on the repository as if you were the code owner. Instead, it shows the `X` commits with their actual authors, even if these developers are not part of your team and you haven't ever seen their names.

Comment: Thanks,  for ref how would you fix this?

Comment: Fixing it? 1) There is no problem with the existing behaviour so there isn't really anything to fix. 2) That would be cheating! You don't want these commits to appear under your name, do you?

Answer (score 0):

When you form a pull request, you choose both the branch with your commits, and the original branch you want to treat as the source you started with.  By default, we focus on the branch we're pulling from, and completely ignore the other one.  If it isn't the branch you thought, your pull request can contain a bunch of irrelevant stuff.

How do avoid this?  You more carefully choose the two branches.

How do you fix this one?  Not sure.  Probably easiest to delete this pull request and start a new one.  If there are comments, that's bad form, and you should just ignore the extra commits in your pull request.